# Bat File to Trigger a program hotkey

Tags: batch-file

I have to record a session with a program and want the windows task (1hour) to run a .Bat file to hit for example "F1" to stop the recording then run another .bat file to shutdown the pc.
I dont have problem with turning off pc but the one for "F1".

This is the code i thought it gonna work.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\ShareX"
Start "" /b sharex.exe 
timeout /T 5 /nobreak >nul 
%SendKeys% "{F1}"
timeout /T 5 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /IM sharex.exe /F
```

Thanks

Comment: _"This is the code i thought it gonna work."_.... I have been looking for 30 seconds flat and I do not see any code.

Comment: I edited your question, please remove the comment.

Comment: ok, so now that we have some code.. where and how did you define `%sendkeys%` You are using it  but never show where you define it?

Comment: I think by the code I wrote its going to cmd. Im not sure
I assigned F1 in "ShareX Program" to be the stop hotkey.
when I run the bat file its responding with
{{ '"{F1}"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.}}
So I have no idea what to do.

Comment: ok, but you are executing a variable called `%sendkeys%` which would be a vbs script which needs to exists somewhere.. `%sendkeys%` is not a magic function, you actually have to create the variable before you can use it.

Comment: So I need one line to define the function.
like set SendKeys= (something) ?

Comment: Yes. But sendkeys is a vbs script, you need to tell the script to use it, so first you need to create the sendkeys script. Also you do not need to actually define it as a variable, you can just run it from the batch file including its path.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard
path ? I have to search for that, I dont know :)

Comment: search google for `sendkeys.vbs`

Comment: I did some tries but always getting that.
{{is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.}}

Comment: _"I did some tries"_ But I cannot guess what you tried.. You need to edit your question showing a complete example with input, code and expected output and errors you receive.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood this question... 
This will create the sendkey.vbs to you and run it in your code...

{ sorry my *limited* English }

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"
>"!_temp_vbs!"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ objShell.AppActivate "sharex.exe"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({F1})"
    )

cd /d "C:\Program Files\ShareX" & Start "" /b sharex.exe
timeout /t 3600 /nobreak && start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" 

>nul 2>nul ((
tasklist | findstr /lic:"ShareX.exe" 
) && ( 
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul & taskkill /f /im "ShareX.exe" &  del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!"
) || (
call shotdown_pc.bat & exit /b
)) >nul 2>nul
```